# Redirection to link in webview_flutter: ^4.2.1 is not working in android build

Tags: flutter, flutter-dependencies, webview-flutter, flutter-web3

Redirection to a link in side webview of `webview_flutter: ^4.2.1` is not working on android build but its working fine on Ipad and Iphone

here Is the controller i have used

```
 controller.setJavaScriptMode(JavaScriptMode.unrestricted);
    controller.setBackgroundColor(context.resources.color.gradientBottom);
    controller.setNavigationDelegate(NavigationDelegate(
      onPageStarted: (String url) {
        print('url loding : $url');
        BlocProvider.of<BrokerDashboardBloc>(context)
            .add(OnUrlLoadStartEvent());
      },
      onWebResourceError: (WebResourceError error) {
        print("error : ${error.description}");
      },
      onPageFinished: (String url) {
        BlocProvider.of<BrokerDashboardBloc>(context).add(OnUrlLoadEndEvent());
      },
      onNavigationRequest: (NavigationRequest request) {
        return NavigationDecision.navigate;
      },
      onUrlChange: (UrlChange change) {
      },

    ));
```

I wants to redirect inside webveiw from a link inside webpage